# The page isn’t redirecting properly - Laravel 7

Tags: authentication, laravel-7

I am new to laravel and i have implemented login without auth:make.
now, i am implementing authentication (without login no one can access any pages).

```
This is my routes/web.php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'UsersController@dashboard');
    Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index');
    Route::get('/users/index', 'UsersController@index');
    Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login');
    Route::get('/users/login', 'UsersController@login');
    //Route::get('/users/login', 'UsersController@login')->name('login');
    Route::get('/users/logout', 'UsersController@logout');

   Route::resources([
        'users' => 'UsersController',
    ]);
});
```

I added the below code in my UsersController

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Below is the code of Middleware\Authenticate.php

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login', app()->getLocale());
    }
}
```

But it gave me error "Route [login] not defined.". so i added the code in routes/web.php

> Route::get('/users/login', 'UsersController@login')->name('login');
> But then it gives me error: The page isn’t redirecting properly
> can anybody help, what i am doing wrong or anything else need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Change `route()` with `url()` because you didn't define routes. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: I defined it. But then it gives me error: The page isn’t redirecting properly. I got the issue. actually i defined '$this->middleware('auth');' in userscontroller. so login method was not publically available. and caused the error. silly mistake.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined it. But then it gives me error: The page isn’t redirecting properly. I got the issue. actually i defined '$this->middleware('auth');' in userscontroller. so login method was not publicly available. and caused the error. silly mistake.!

Answer (score 0):

In your `redirectTo` method, you are calling the route helper function.
It uses the route name but you haven't specified it.

You have to specify a name for your login route by chaining the name method onto the route definition like:

```
Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login')->name('login');
```